# Laravel with xampp

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

I need to understand this behavior.

I use xampp for web development. I start to apache server in the xampp gui and then I can start my projects in the browser via localhost...

Since yesterday I have added laravel to my mac book. My project is in the xampp htdocs folder and I want to use it witch xampp. But when the xampp apache server instance is running, nothing is happened to my laravel project until I run php artisan serve in the cmd.

How can I combine larael with xampp?
And what exactly does php artisan serve do? Start another apache server instance?

Comment: Do you have to use xampp? Laravel has a great tool for development on Mac: [Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/valet)

Answer (score 3):

The artisan command is just a command line utility for laravel.  The serve command just starts up the PHP server.

to run it without artisan you can Configure a server virtual-host (Apache or Nginx) which have the public directory of your project as root directory. Since you are using a MAC I can't exactly instruct you to how to do that.

**NOTE**

[this will help to create the virtual host. but i haven't tried that](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/how-to-set-up-virtual-hosts-in-apache-on-macos-osx-sierra/)

Answer (score 1):

sorry i can't comment due to reputation :/ i use lumen (rest api of laravel) with xampp and it works fine. Can you provide somemore details? 
I also think the path is the problem. Which path you use to access it via a browser? for lumen its /htdocs/project/public/ so in browser: http://localhost/project/public/
there i can access the api. should be similar for full laravel project?

Answer (score 1):

Create virtual host and point it to laravel_directory/public/index.php and restart apache.

Creating apache virtual host:
http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/25/creating-an-apache-virtualhost

If you don't want to do that load, localhost/lara_dir/public/index.php

`index.php` is where all the requests go through.